# Why can I see all these people in Trello? And what can they see about me?

Tags: privacy, trello

When I start typing to add my friends in Trello, I see all these people I don't know! What's up with that? Are you showing my boards to the public?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't let you see other people's boards unless they've been explicitly shared with you or made public.

We do let anyone invite you, or you invite anyone, to a board, in the same way you can invite anyone to link to you on a social network like Facebook or LinkedIn.

For instance, you can see me, but not anything about me because we're not in the same organization and don't have any shared boards.

https://trello.com/rich

**EDIT**

We have posted an FAQ on privacy and security.

https://trello.com/privacy

Comment: Can you make it clear that you're part of the Trello development team when you answer your questions. Just so everything's above board according to the [FAQ](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/faq#promotion)

Comment: Sure! Can you give me an example of how others have done this gracefully?

Comment: Just stating that you're one of the developers both in your profile and in the answer should do it.

Comment: @RichArmstrong, does the Trello Development board also count as a shared board that allows people to see your details?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Can you clarify?